# How can I recursively delete all empty directories?

Tags: directories

That is, if I have

```
-empty-dir-a/
-nonempty-dir-a/
  -empty-dir-a/
    -empty-dir-a/
  file-a
file-a
file-b
```

I would like

```
-nonempty-dir-a/
  file-a
file-a
file-b
```

---

I'm aware that there are many OS-specific solutions to this, but I'd like to stick to elisp, ideally `:)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the find tool.

<kbd>M-!</kbd> `find . -empty -type d -delete` <kbd>return</kbd>

Here it is wrapped in a function that confirms the delete:

```lisp
(defun delete-empty-dirs ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((dirs (split-string (shell-command-to-string "find -X $(pwd) -empty -type d") "[ \n]" t)))
    (when (yes-or-no-p (format "Delete %d empty directories? " (length dirs)))
      (with-temp-buffer (shell-command "find -X $(pwd) -empty -type d -delete")))))
```

Comment: Lovely on *nix, but Windows (et al.) don't have a `find` command. There's always Cygwin for those how are allowed to install it, but it doesn't come default.

Comment: Make your life easier on windows with: http://www.mingw.org

Comment: @InHarmsWay I have Cygwin actually, after trying MinGW and finding it insufficient. …Cygwin is also insufficient. :(

Comment: @SeanAllred Perhaps it's Windows that's insufficient.   I was happy enough to find Mingw had a decent find and grep, and other basic commands. But yes, it's all more painful than it should be.

Answer (score 2):

This requires the following functions from [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el), available from MELPA:

- `f-directories` returns a list of directories in the given directory
- `f-entries` returns all files and folders in the given directory

```lisp
(defun *-delete-empty-directories (root-directory)
  "Recursively delete empty directories in ROOT-DIRECTORY.

When called from dired, `dired-current-directory' is used for
ROOT-DIRECTORY."

  ;; Interface
  (interactive (list (if (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
                         (expand-file-name (dired-current-directory))
                       (read-from-minibuffer "Root directory: "))))
  (when (or (null root-directory) (string= "" root-directory))
    (user-error "No root directory provided"))
  (when (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
    (unless (yes-or-no-p (format "Delete all non-empty directories in `%s'? "
                                 root-directory))
      (user-error "Directory `%s' has been left untouched" root-directory)))

  ;; Implementation
  (require 'f)
  (let ((entries (f-directories root-directory)))
    (while entries
      (let ((curdir (car entries)))
        (when (f-directories curdir)
          (*-delete-empty-directories curdir))
        (unless (f-entries curdir)
          (delete-directory curdir)
          (message "Directory deleted: `%s'" curdir))
        (setq entries (cdr entries))))))
```

Comment: Presumably, [this](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) is the library `f.el` that you are requiring.

Comment: @Drew correct – I thought it was sortof common knowledge to look for `foo.el` when foo is required (like `\usepackage{foo}` needs `foo.sty` in LaTeX).

Comment: @Drew Edited for clarity :)